# Rails path helpers without routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

We are in the process of taking a few pages out of our rails app to be served separately (they are a few static pages with some content being managed through a cms). The urls will stay the same. Our own routing system in front of the servers will decide which request should go to the rails app and which to the static part.

My question is about path helpers that we use quite a bit throughout the rails app, such as `link_to about_path` that generate `mahwebsite.com/about`. As I understand I can just leave them be, they will still generate correct urls. My only concern is that for them to work I'll have to keep the routings in the routes file, which will have to be connected to the dummy controller methods. Seems like a lot of redundant code just to fool rails into creating path helpers.

Alternatively, I can hard-code links to the static pages. But before I start replacing a whole lot of code, I'd like to know if there is a clean Railsy way to keep the path helpers without having to route to the redundant controllers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create your own helper method? E.G.

```
# application_controller.rb
def about_path
  "mahwebsite.com/about"
end
helper_method :about_path
alias_method :about_url, :about_path
```

This will overwrite any Rails helper method and do exactly what you're after :)

Hope this helps - give me a shout if you've any questions or comments.

Comment: Did this help at all @redFur?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
resources :custom_pages, only: [:your_options] do
  get :view/:page_id_or_whatever_for_identify
end
```

and do the following content with the controller?